# I am trying to develop a spark application with kafka, but I get a cNoClassDefFoundError

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am learning spark streaming with kafka (using scala API), and I am trying to develop a simple application to bind a kafka application to a streaming application. The compilation with sbt is OK, but when I do spark-submit I always get the same error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

The Spark version I have installed is 2.3.0.

My build.sbt file is:

```
name := "Linking" 
mainClass := Some("Main")
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0" % "provided" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.3.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.2.0"
```

and the main source file is:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe


object KafkaStreaming {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
println("Hello, world!")

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092,anotherhost:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )

    val topics = Array("topicA", "topicB")
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )

    stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value))

}
}
```

I have research and got two solutions. Problem with library versions, and including --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly in spark-submit, but neither of them worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add the full exception string?

Comment: For starters there is Spark version mismatch in your dependencies.